# __init.py__ and pytest - cannot import base modules when __init__.py present

Tags: python, pytest

I have a Python project in which I have code organized as follows:

```
/package
   LICENSE
   README.md
   setup.py
   /project
      /mod_1
         mod_1.py
         __init__.py
         /tests
            test_mod_1.py
      /mod_2
         mod_2.py
         __init__.py
         /tests
            test_mod_2.py
      object_factory.py
      __init__.py
```

The object_factory.py file contains a class that is used to build objects defined in mod_1.py and mod_2.py.

Within the tests, each test file imports the class from object_factory.py.  When I run pytest from the /project directory, it complains that the object_factory module does not exist.  If, however, I remove __init__.py from each of the mod_# directories, it works fine.

I've read many blog posts and Python help posts describing the intent of __init__.py as well as pytest, but I cannot seem to sort out this one detail.

Comment: Your package is named "project" and its parent directory needs to be in the python path somewhere. By the time a project reaches this size, its usually best to make it an installable package by writing  setup.py. You can use "develop" mode for your tests. You likely also want to part your entire package in another parent directory for source control.

Comment: Yes, I have a setup.py file at the same level as the /project directory (I added that to the original post), and the whole thing is in parent directory which is a git repository.  I don't follow how the presence of the setup.py affects things, though.  As I mentioned, if I delete the __init.py__ files from the mod_# directories, pytest is happy and the tests run fine.  I can't find any explanation for why they should be present or not.

Comment: A also added more details about the overall directory structure.  I apologize for leaving that out originally, as it may be important.

Note that I also install the package with [pip -e install .]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. `__init__.py` files

> I've read many blog posts and Python help posts describing the intent of **init**.py as well as pytest, but I cannot seem to sort out this one detail.

##### Answering your question: `__init__.py` files are used to mark your directory  as a **Python package**. This means that Python will look for submodules inside that directory, so you can import them.

Alongside, pytest requires you to write tests for your package in a separate **packages**. It means that you should consider putting `__init__.py` in your tests directory.

### 2. Project structure

Talking about project structure, pytest provides two basic test layouts in their [Good integration practices](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules)

#### The first one is Tests outside application code

```
pyproject.toml
setup.cfg
mypkg/
    __init__.py
    app.py
    view.py
tests/
    test_app.py
    test_view.py
    ...
```

as documentation says, this approach has a bunch of benefits:

- Your tests can run against an installed version after executing pip install ..
- Your tests can run against the local copy with an editable install after executing pip install --editable ..

#### The second one is Tests as part of application code

```
pyproject.toml
setup.cfg
mypkg/
    __init__.py
    app.py
    view.py
    test/
        __init__.py
        test_app.py
        test_view.py
        ...
```

**This is actually your case.**

Turning back to your project structure, here is a couple of things I want to highlight:

1. As I've said before, consider making your test directories **packages**.
2. Take a look at [PEP 423 - Avoiding deep nesting](https://peps.python.org/pep-0423/#avoid-deep-nesting). You probably don't want to complicate your package, therefore, don’t put your package modules in subdirectories unless you *really need to*.

Taking into account all the above, I would recommend you change your structure a little bit, so it looks like the following:

```
/package
   LICENSE
   README.md
   setup.py
   /project
      mod_1.py
      mod_2.py
      /tests
         __init__.py
         test_mod_1.py
         test_mod_2.py
      object_factory.py
      __init__.py
```

In this case, you should run you tests with the command

```py
pytest --pyargs project
```

> Note that you have to import your modules into `object_factory.py` using `from project import test_mod_X`

##### However, you probably don’t even want to distribute your test along with your application.

If I'm right, you can also use the first approach:

```
/package
   LICENSE
   README.md
   setup.py
   /project
      __init__.py
      mod_1.py
      mod_2.py
      object_factory.py
   /tests
      __init__.py
      test_mod_1.py
      test_mod_2.py
```

and run your test with `pytest`. It seems more readable and straightforward to me.

> You may also find it useful to look at [Invoking pytest versus python -m pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/pythonpath.html#invoking-pytest-versus-python-m-pytest)

##### One more thing

There is one more thing I would like to add. It's something that isn't directly related to your problem but can cause confusion and, as a result, other problems later on when your code is more complex.

**You may have confused the names project and package.**

The ***project*** is a folder in which all your files are located - README, LICENSE, setup.py, etc.

The ***package*** is the directory where `__init__.py`, your code, and modules reside.

With that in mind, **swap these names around** to make your code more readable for yourself and others.

Comment: Thank you for these details.  I truly appreciate it and it helps clarify things significantly.  Regarding nesting, this is where things get sticky.  I will take your advice and work on restructuring the overall package.

Comment: And, you are correct about project and package - I have them switched from how they should be in the directory structure figure.

Comment: I am very glad that I could help you, it means a lot to me. I wish you good luck with your project 

Comment: Quick follow up - this answer solved my problem.  After restructuring my project as described, everything works fine and I actually understand things a bit more.  Thanks again!